# Vue.js - using Vuelidate url domain should match email domain

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2, vue-component, vuelidate

I have two inputs field : `url` and `email`

I'm using `Vuelidate` and I want to make a custom validator where it checks if the url domain name is equal to the email domain name.

**Valid example :**

url: `(https://)www.mydomain.example`

email: `johndoe@mydomain.example`

**Invalid example :**

url: `(https://)www.mydomain.example`

email: `johndoe@somedomaine.example`

validations object :

```
validations: {
    form: {
      url: { required, url, maxLength: maxLength(2083) },
      email: { required, email, maxLength: maxLength(255) },
      lastName: { required, maxLength: maxLength(100) },
      firstName: { required, maxLength: maxLength(100) }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Just break string and match with string after www

Comment: please provide your `validations` object

Comment: ok updated, i don't know what regex should i put..

Comment: "if the url domain name is equal to the email domain name." this assumption will fail in many cases... for example a corporation may have its website at `acme.example` but using `@corp.acme.example` instead or with same domain name in another TLDs (for only 2 real life examples out of many other cases you can find). So what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `custom validator` called `matchUrl` as follow :

```
  const matchUrl=(value, vm) => 
   value.substring(value.indexOf("@")+1) ===vm.url.substring(vm.url.indexOf(".")+1);
```

And use it as :

```
validations: {
 form: {
  url: { required, url, maxLength: maxLength(2083) },
  email: { required,matchUrl, email, maxLength: maxLength(255) },
  lastName: { required, maxLength: maxLength(100) },
   firstName: { required, maxLength: maxLength(100) }
 }
},
```

check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko756xr435) working example